# What is the equivalent of apply(this, arguments) in coffeescript?

Tags: coffeescript

In javascript you would write something like:

```
method.apply(this,arguments);
```

However, how do you translate it to coffeescript?:

```
method.apply(@, arguments)
```

Is there a different name for the arguments variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`arguments`is available in coffee-script, too. So you can do:

`method.apply @, arguments`

Answer (score 17):

Using splats you can use the cleaner coffeescript syntax:

```
caller: ->
  @method arguments...
```

The above compiles to the following Javascript:

```
caller: function() {
  return this.method.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: that's some nice coffeescript!

Answer (score 2):

If you want it to work exactly like javascript, you probably could, but coffeescript has "splats" for what you are probably trying to accomplish. Here's the explanation from coffeescript.org:

```
gold = silver = rest = "unknown"

awardMedals = (first, second, others...) ->
  gold   = first
  silver = second
  rest   = others

contenders = [
  "Michael Phelps"
  "Liu Xiang"
  "Yao Ming"
  "Allyson Felix"
  "Shawn Johnson"
  "Roman Sebrle"
  "Guo Jingjing"
  "Tyson Gay"
  "Asafa Powell"
  "Usain Bolt"
]

awardMedals contenders...

alert "Gold: " + gold
alert "Silver: " + silver
alert "The Field: " + rest
```

Comment: I don't understand how this answers his question?

Comment: it does actually, i found the same quote a minute ago

Comment: The goal of apply is running a function on a specific object (setting 'this' yourself), I don't understand how this is done in the example, would you mind explaining?